# Application to periodically update desktop with new images from Flickr tag search?

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop, flickr

Are there any applications I can use to periodically download new images from a Flickr tag search and update my desktop picture (preferably with support for multiple monitors)?

Comment: I'd like to create one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DeskLickr](http://desklickr.isnot.tv/) is a few years old, and I've not tried it, but it should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had to turn off the "Change picture" option in the Desktop and Screen Saver prefpane, but it works like a charm!